# How to grep specific query in log

Tags: sed, log4j, grep, aix

The following is my log.

```
2011-03-10 20:34:16,657  INFO [jdbc.sqlonly]
SELECT          COL1
    ,   COL2    -- some comments may be here
    ,   COL3
FROM        TABLE_A
WHERE       COL4 = 'some_text'
/* [related.classname] : some comments go here */
2011-03-10 20:34:16,658 DEBUG [another.class.name] blahblah
.
.
.
2011-03-10 20:34:16,843  INFO [jdbc.sqlonly]
SELECT         MAX(COL_A)
FROM        TABLE_B
WHERE       COL_T < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
/* [other.classname] : some comments go here */
2011-03-10 20:34:16,844 DEBUG [other.class.name2] blahblah
.
.
```

I wanna grep this query with tail -f command, and catch ONLY related.classname.
Because every query include line feed character, It can't be helpful to use grep command.
How can I do this?
I've concerned about possible command using sed, like the following.

```
tail -f some.log | sed -n '/jdbc\.sqlonly/,/2011-03-10 /p'
```

It can help to find only query, not debug log, but didn't catch the associated classname(related.classname).
Plz help me. Ah, my server is AIX.

Comment: Can  you show us what you would like as your output?

Answer (score 1):

Awk is well suited for this type of task.  Fundamentally, an awk script processes one line at a time, but allows you to modify/read global variables while processing each line.   To apply awk to this problem, you could create a mini-state machine that remembers when processing a line "inside" a log entry and print whatever information is desired from "matching" entries.

Here is an example awk program.  The `BEGIN` block is executed once before processing any input, while the main block is executed once per line -- `$0` contains the entire line contents.

```
BEGIN{
    inmatch=0
    last=""
}
{
    if(match($0,"INFO|DEBUG")){
        if(inmatch){
            print last
        }
        inmatch=0
    }
    if(match($0,"jdbc\.sqlonly")){
        inmatch=1
    }
    last=$0
}
```

This script prints the last line of each log entry that started with a line containing `jdbc.sqlonly`.  The start of a new log entry is defined as any line that contains `INFO` or `DEBUG`.  The regular expression parameter to the match() function can be easily tweaked.  To run the script, store it in a file and invoke as follows:

```
$ cat log.file | awk -f script.awk
/* [related.classname] : some comments go here */
/* [other.classname] : some comments go here */
```

"Throw-away" or one-line awk scripts can also be built at the command-line, which is convenient for temporary solutions that do not justify a fully featured scripting language.

```
$ cat test.file | awk 'BEGIN{inmatch=0;last=""}{if(match($0,"INFO|DEBUG")){if(inmatch){print last}inmatch=0} if(match($0,"jdbc\.sqlonly")){inmatch=1}last=$0}'
/* [related.classname] : some comments go here */
/* [other.classname] : some comments go here */
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sed I use, the range command appears to be greedy, and is matching the last date.

You could  egrep for 'INFO|DEBUG' and manipulate that as needed.

I hope this helps.

P.S. as you appear to be a new user, if you get an answer that helps you please remember to mark it as accepted, or give it a + (or -) as a useful answer

Comment: Again, it will help your chances in getting a good result if you indicate exactly what you want your results to be, given the log files you have posted. (you **can** edit your original post). ... So you want  your output to be just `/* [related.classname] : some comments go here */` AND NOT `/* [other.classname] : some comments go here */`... AND I'm assuming that the value for 'related.classname' changes otherwise you would just search for related. Is that your issue? Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one I use it ...

```
tail -F yourLog.log | sed -nr ':main; /^2011.*sql/ { :loop; p; n; /^2011/ b main; b loop} '
```

Here 2011 is the pattern of each log line start with. sql is the word I am searching for.